# How to add (ssh) key to IBM Bluemix DevOps Services' git repository?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

How can I add an (ssh) key to IBM Bluemix DevOps Services' git repository, so that I don't have to authenticate via username/password whenever I push or pull?

Answer (score 1):

Aparently SSH is not supported at the moment according to the documentation.
https://hub.jazz.net/docs/reference/gitclient/

Answer (score 0):

Per [git client documentation](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/reference/gitclient/):

> Note: DevOps Services supports the HTTPS protocol for Git URLs. The SSH and Git protocols are not supported.

Sorry to for the inconvenience.